# Regular Expression To Find All Characters Except x,a,n,-

Tags: php, regex

This is my first post here.  I've started writing a few and always managed to figure it out on my own.  Alas, regular expressions make me want to beat my face on the street and I'm stuck.

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will check a string for any character that isn't an x, a, n, or -.  Here's what I have:

```
    preg_replace( '/^[^xan\-]+$/' , 'x' , $this->str_key_mask )
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but I've tried adding, changing, and removing metacharacters and can't get the result I want.

For instance, if I pass in xan-nax-jxy, I want to get back xan-nax-xxx due replacing the j and y with x.  If I pass in xxx-aaa-nnn, it should return xxx-aaa-nnn since nothing needs replacing.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what programming language are we talking about?

Answer (score 2):

With the `^` and `$` anchors, you will only match strings that are composed of *entirely* characters that are not x, a, n, or -.  Since you want to match each of those characters separately and replace each one with 'x', just remove the anchors and the repetition:

```
preg_replace( '/[^xan\-]/' , 'x' , $this->str_key_mask )
```

Removing the repetition is necessary if you want a string like 'jy' to become 'xx'.  If instead you want 'jy' to become 'x', keep the `+` after your character class so that consecutive characters are replaced together.

Comment: interesting. would that change only a single character or is that some kind of `preg_replace_all` behaviour?

Comment: oh, it's php? then your initial code was correct. in php preg_replace replaces every occurence.

Answer (score 1):

Your `preg_replace` will only match a string that consists completely of `[^xan\-]`, because of `^` which matches the begining of the line, and `$` which matches the end of the line. If you need to replace a couple of occurrences of character groups in a string, I'd recommend using

```
preg_replace('/[^xan-]/', 'x', $this->str_key_mask)
```

and running this several times, until the string does not change anymore.

*NOTE*: The behaviour of `preg_replace` differs between programming languages. In your language it might as well replace all occurrences (as is does in PHP, for example).

Maybe there is a better way to do this, but I cant think of something right now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace( '/[^xan-]/' , 'x' , $this->str_key_mask)
```